# Error : Unable to connect successfully to server. Trying another node...Too many open files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

We got reports of API failures . While investigating it appears the  servers was logging nothing but errors like:

Logs :

```
2023-10-05 03:15:14.087+0000|pool-2-thread-1|INFO|AttachmentManagerImpl|Running executeAttachmentScheduler at Thu Oct 05 03:15:14 UTC 2023
2023-10-05 03:15:14.087+0000|pool-2-thread-1|ERROR|ClusterClientImpl|Unable to connect successfully to {{Server}}. Trying another node...Too many open files
2023-10-05 03:15:14.088+0000|pool-2-thread-1|ERROR|ClusterClientImpl|Unable to connect successfully to {{Server}}. Trying another node...Too many open files
2023-10-05 03:15:14.088+0000|pool-2-thread-1|ERROR|ClusterClientImpl|Unable to connect successfully to  {{Server}}. Trying another node...Too many open files
2023-10-05 03:15:14.088+0000|pool-2-thread-1|ERROR|ClusterClientImpl|Unable to connect successfully to  {{Server}} . Trying another node...Too many open files
2023-10-05 03:15:14.088+0000|pool-2-thread-1|ERROR|ClusterClientImpl|Unable to connect successfully to  {{Server}}. Trying another node...Too many open files
2023-10-05 03:15:14.088+0000|pool-2-thread-1|ERROR|ClusterClientImpl|Unable to connect successfully to  {{Server}}. Trying another node...Too many open files
2023-10-05 03:15:14.088+0000|pool-2-thread-1|WARN|ClusterClientImpl|All nodes in the riak cluster are unreachable!
2023-10-05 03:15:14.088+0000|pool-2-thread-1|INFO|AttachmentManagerImpl|Riak cluset is down, so attachment outbound is not sending.
```

tomcat status before restart :

```
  jws5-tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jws5-tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jws5-tomcat.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-09-25 13:14:31 UTC; 1 weeks 2 days ago
 Main PID: 64480 (java)
    Tasks: 215
   Memory: 9.4G
   CGroup: /system.slice/jws5-tomcat.service
           └─64480 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Dhydra.logdir=/opt/rh/jws5/root/usr/share/tomcat/logs/ -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/heapd...

Oct 05 12:53:35 server[64480]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: 05-Oct-2023 12:53:36.132 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-Acceptor] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run Socket accept failed
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:421)
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:249)
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:546)
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:79)
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:129)
Oct 05 12:53:36 server[64480]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I gathered some data from server and restarted tomcat . After restart it appears to be processing things normally again.
Kindly help me to find the root cause and fix this in future.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running out of open files in Tomcat. This is causing, presumably, the Riak Java client, to not be able to connect to Riak because it can't open a socket as it has no free files.

As you mentioned that a Tomcat restart seemed to fix the problem, this does suggest that the files limit is the issue. You probably want to either increase the number of open files for your server or make sure that files are closed when possible.

The problem is most probably within the application you are running on Tomcat. However, in the offchance that it is the Riak Java client, can you share the Riak Java client and Riak KV version so we can check whether there are any known issues with the combination you are using?